# Implementing object interface results in error: not a valid class

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement the following interface:

```
<?php
namespace Spatie\WebhookClient\SignatureValidator;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Spatie\WebhookClient\WebhookConfig;

interface SignatureValidator
{
    public function isValid(Request $request, WebhookConfig $config): bool;
}
```

This implementation results in the below error:

```
<?php
namespace App\Handler;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Spatie\WebhookClient\WebhookConfig;
use Spatie\WebhookClient\Exceptions\InvalidConfig;
use Spatie\WebhookClient\SignatureValidator\SignatureValidator as SignatureValidator;

class MySignatureValidator implements SignatureValidator
{
    public function isValid(Request $request, WebhookConfig $config): bool
    {
        $signature = $request->header($config->signatureHeaderName);

        if (! $signature) {
            return false;
        }

        $signingSecret = $config->signingSecret;

        if (empty($signingSecret)) {
            throw InvalidConfig::signingSecretNotSet();
        }

        $computedSignature = hash_hmac('sha256', $request->getContent(), $signingSecret);

        return true;
        //return hash_equals($signature, $computedSignature);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Spatie\WebhookClient\Exceptions\InvalidConfig:
`App\Handler\MySignatureValidator` is not a valid signature validator class.
A valid signature validator is a class that implements
`Spatie\WebhookClient\SignatureValidator\SignatureValidator`
```

Comment: Can you try hacking [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-webhook-client/blob/1c171f3c369ce30f19a5c87d6b754db96e161cd6/src/WebhookConfig.php#L40) to see if `instanceof` works instead?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I'm also having the same issue